# Does spark use memorization when applying a transformation?

Tags: apache-spark

For example : assume we have the following dataset :

| Student | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 10 |
| Sam | 30 |
| Tom | 30 |
| Vlad | 30 |

when spark executes the following transformation :

```
df.withColumn("Grade_minus_average", df("Grade") - lit(average) )
```

will spark compute "30 - average" 3 times or will it reuse the computation ?

(let's assume there is only one partition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

An excellent source: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/catalyst-tungsten-apache-sparks-speeding-engine-deepak-rajak/

> **Constant folding** is the process of recognizing and evaluating constant expressions at compile time rather than computing them at
> runtime. This is not in any particular way specific to Catalyst. It is
> just a standard compilation technique and its benefits should be
> obvious. It is better to compute expression once than repeat this for
> each row.

As you have a constant and a variable, it will be done for each row and there is no process within Spark, that at run-time track if the previous invocation had the same input, nor a cache of previous values outcomes.